# Scope tags: "on-topic" vs "off-topic" vs "scope"

Tags: discussion, support, scope, tag-synonyms

Funny but I thought I had been using a [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag here like on other SE sites I use but it seems not to exist after all.

We do have an [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag but I don't think this is great since discussions of what's on-topic invariably also go into what's off topic.

I think the lead tag for this trio should be [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) with two synonyms [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) both redirecting to it.

For those of you who are programmers you can think of it this way. What makes a better name for a variable: `big`, `small`, or `size`?

Comment: Eh, what's this about?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: This question is about which tag or tags is the best way to handle topics allowable questions on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done. Sorry for long period of ignoring.

Answer (score 3):

On [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the tag is called [`allowed-topics`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-topics).

It was expected that other meta sites would follow the tagging of MSO. Meta sites are even pre-populated with a selection of tags, though [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) doesn't seem to be in them. There's a [long-planned feature to copy tag wikis automatically from MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites), which would help.

Comment: Well I like "scope" better than "allowed topics" personally even though I didn't invent it. In any case we can also merge into whatever standard tag gets thrown at us at some point too.

Comment: I've just noticed that `scope` also exists on MSO. I proposed it as a synonym of `allowed-topics` because `allowed-topics` gets more use, but I also prefer `scope`. I'm going to try to raise an MSO mod about this.